# One div (one div on the left, 4 divs under below on the right)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get in the div 'header', one div on the left side (65% width of the page) and 4 divs on the right side, under below.

I've tried so many things, but the divs on the right side are always doubling the height of the left div.

http://jsfiddle.net/Skydance/xxEDE/

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">

    <div id="logogedeelte">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>

    <div id="navigationbar">
        <div class="home"> <img src="images/logo.png"></div>
        <div class="collectie"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>
        <div class="contact"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>
        <div class="overons"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: In the fiddle, they are not.

Comment: The link is added @matewka

Comment: Yes, I mean this link. These divs out there are not doubling the height of the left div. Maybe you might want to explain it a little bit more or attach an image?

Comment: When you have an image in the left div, it's actually do. I will make a screenshot

Comment: Screenshot: http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/8572/ewvn.png

Comment: Does this screenshot represent how it look right now or how it __should__ look? Because in the fiddle the layout is exactly the same.

Comment: Looks right now.
The four right div's does have to take the 100% height of the left div. So each div needs to be 25%.. because the 4 div's makes the fully 100% height, right? That is what I want :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case height of these divs depends on images height. So you can only set it by adding to your css following lines :

```
#logogedeelte, #navigationbar {
    display: table-cell;
}
```